# How to retain this drop down box created space in my PoP Up Model in MVC C#?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I designed a Pop-Up Model. I use one drop down, but I don't know why this much space come in between one drop down and another text box. Image attached below.[image]

My coding part is below:

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                   <p class="form_text1">Data 1<span class="red">*</span></p>
                    <input type="text" id="Data 1" name="Data 1" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <p class="form_text1">Data 2 <span class="red">*</span></p>
                    <input type="text" id="Data 2" name="Data 2" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <p class="form_text1">Data 3*@ <span class="red">*</span></p>
                    @Html.DropDownList("Data 3", new SelectList(@ViewBag._Data 3, "Key", "Value"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <p class="form_text1">Data 4<span class="red">*</span></p>
                    <input type="text" id="Data 4" name="Data 4" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <p class="form_text1">Data 5@<span class="red">*</span></p>
                    <input type="text" id="Data 5" name="Data 5" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <p class="form_text1">Data 6@<span class="red">*</span></p>
                    <input type="text" id="Data 6" name="Data 6" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <p class="form_text1">Data 7<span class="red"></span></p>
                    <input type="text" id="Data 7" name="Data 7" class="form-control">
                </div></div>
```

Comment: hi i have replace selectList with static select tag. i found no problem working fine for me .. here is the link https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/NgxdXX?editors=1010

Comment: put the rendered HTML here.

Comment: @ChandraShekhar hi sir, its not working for me. also I pass the value using viewbag to the above dropdown..In static select tag, how to pass viewbag values?